# Changing Data in the application, verify in the Database (UFT)

Tags: sql-server, automated-tests, hp-uft, uft14

I have a test scenario,

I have an application in which Customer name, customer's phone, email and account number are present. I need to verify the data is the same data present in the database and in the application. Also if there is new data entered in the database the values in the application will be changed, so need to verify those values.

How can you do it? any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please specify the technology stack that you're using for your tests and application.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it is expected that research and an attempt to solve the issue is done before posting questions. I would suggest that you first go through the documentation/online tutorial for hp-uft and attempt to create you scenario. Then, if you run into an issue, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: I am using UFT 14.52 and application is a Web based application and i am using VBs

Comment: Here is a way to do it in case someone else needs it, this a database checkpoint

Comment: strExpFirstname = "name"
Set oDB = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
'Defining the connection
oDB.ConnectionString = "this can be found in database"
oDB.Open
SQL="enter your query here'" 
Set oRec = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oRec.Open SQL,oDB
'oREC.RecordCount(how many counts are there in the record set coiunt)
If oRec.EOF = False Then

 strACTFIrstname = ORec.Fields("name of the table").Value
 If Ucase(Trim(strExpFirstname)) = Ucase(Trim(strACTFirstName)) Then
  msgbox "name mactch"
  Else
  msgbox " name not matched"
 End If
End If
oRec.Close
oDB.Close